# Jquery Concat JSON objects does not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create product quantity field. I have done it is working properly but when i add Numeric IDs in code then it is not working. Please view the code I hope you will easily understand my problem.

### HTML CODE

```
<input type='button' value='-' id="qtyMinus<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>" class='qty-minus qone01' field='quantity' />
<input type='text' name="quantity[<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" class='shopping-qty qone02' />
<input type='button' value='+' id="qtyPlus<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>" class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
```

### JS Code

```
 var productIds =  [{"id":"13"},{"id":"14"},{"id":"15"}];


            $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(productIds))).each(function() {  
                var ID = this.id;
                $('#qtyPlus' + ID).click(function(e){
                    // Stop acting like a button
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // Get the field name
                    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
                    // Get its current value
                    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
                    // If is not undefined
                    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    // Increment
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
                    } else {
                    // Otherwise put a 0 there
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
                    }
                });
                // This button will decrement the value till 0
                $('#qtyMinus' + ID).click(function(e) {
                    // Stop acting like a button
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // Get the field name
                    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
                    // Get its current value
                    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
                    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
                    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    // Decrement one
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
                    } else {
                    // Otherwise put a 0 there
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
                    }
                });

            });
```

I need to dynamic js code for each input field but loop does not working properly. But when I alert in loop then its working and showing all ids. Please guide me where i'm wrong.

Comment: `$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(productIds)))` wtf?!

Comment: Why you do javascript->Json->javascript. You only need to do productIds.forEach(blablalba), because jQuery.parseJSON this will return javascript object but not jQuery's object.